# My tableview's cell is not displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**FirstPage.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "StudentPage.h"

@interface FirstPage : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,StudentInfoDelegates>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
- (IBAction)addButtonAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

**FirstPage.m**

```
#import "FirstPage.h"

@interface FirstPage ()

@end

@implementation FirstPage
{
    NSMutableArray *firstPageArray;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
    //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"StudentInfo" sender:sender];
    /*StudentPage *student=[[StudentPage alloc]init];
    student.delegates=self;*/
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//the next following didn't created..
//the RowAtIndexPath are not been executed..

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *concateValue=@""; 

    NSMutableDictionary *studentSecondDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        [cell setIndentationWidth:0.0];

        studentSecondDictionary=[firstPageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *name1=[studentSecondDictionary valueForKey:@"NAME"];
        NSString *regno1=[studentSecondDictionary valueForKey:@"REGNO"];
        NSString *marks1=[studentSecondDictionary valueForKey:@"MARKS"];
        NSString *rank1=[studentSecondDictionary valueForKey:@"RANK"];
        concateValue=[[[[[[name1 stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:regno1]stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:marks1]stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:rank1];
        cell.textLabel.text=concateValue;
    }
    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     return firstPageArray.count;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 50;
}

- (IBAction)addButtonAction:(id)sender {
    StudentPage *stdView=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
   stdView.delegates=self;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:stdView animated:YES];
   //[self.view addSubview:stdView.view];
}

-(void)didFinishSave:(NSMutableArray *)in_studentList{
    firstPageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    firstPageArray=in_studentList;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

**StudentPage.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol StudentInfoDelegates
-(void)didFinishSave:(NSMutableArray*)in_studentList;
@end

@interface StudentPage : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property(assign,nonatomic)id<StudentInfoDelegates> delegates;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *regno;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *marks;    
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *rank;

- (IBAction)save:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

**StudentPage.m**

```
#import "StudentPage.h"
#import "FirstPage.h"
@implementation StudentPage
{
    NSMutableArray *studentArray;
    NSMutableDictionary *StudentDictionary;
}
@synthesize name,regno,marks,rank;
@synthesize delegates;

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (IBAction)save:(UIButton *)sender {
    studentArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    StudentDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [StudentDictionary setValue:name.text forKey:@"NAME"];
    [StudentDictionary setValue:regno.text forKey:@"REGNO"];
    [StudentDictionary setValue:marks.text forKey:@"MARKS"];
    [StudentDictionary setValue:rank.text forKey:@"RANK"];
    [studentArray addObject:StudentDictionary];

    [delegates didFinishSave:studentArray];
    NSLog(@"%@",studentArray);
    FirstPage *firstView=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier1"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstView animated:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: Please format you code properly first

Comment: Have you connected the `delegate` and `datasource` for table view?

Comment: yes, i connected the delegate and datasource for my table view

Comment: Does 'firstPageArray' has any data. check the value 'firstPageArray.count' should be more than 1

Comment: Does program set `delegate` and `dataSource` in `viewDidLoad` work ?

Comment: @Avaan More than 0 is enough, no?

Comment: @vignesh.P The problem seems to be the if statement in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. If a cell is dequeued properly the code within the statement is never called. You've written `if(cell==nil)`. Shouldn't it be `if(cell!=nil)`? Or maybe some of that code should be outside the statement, especially 7 last lines. :)

Comment: @kevin yes u are right. I mean the same.  vignesh... check the condition if(cell == nil) it looks wrong

Answer (score 0):

As @BiWoj said in the comments, you are checking for

```
if (cell==nil)...
```

and rely on that check to go through the first time so you can fill out your data. This is wrong, you instead `dequeue` the `cell` and then when it's not `nil` you can start putting your data in its `views`. The only reason that `cell` will be `nil` is when you `dequeue`, using a non-existent identifier i.e. it should never happen.

Answer (score 0):

First just check your delegate method is getting called or not when you click on save button.

I think you forgot to set delegate to self before

```
[delegates didFinishSave:studentArray];
```

It should be

```
self.delegate = delegates
[delegates didFinishSave:studentArray];
```

If this does not work please check that, you are pushing student page from first page like this

```
- (IBAction)addButtonAction:(id)sender {
StudentPage *stdView=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
 stdView.delegates=self;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:stdView animated:YES];}
```

And one again on your save action method of student page you are pushing first page like this.

```
FirstPage *firstView=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier1"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstView animated:YES];
```

Well i guess instead of that you have to just use

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

There is no need to push again the same controller you just have to pop to base controller.